# Bootstrap import only you need without SASS

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

I don't use Bootstrap, but 1 thing made me use it.
The class collapse with certain button.
I have got more than 2 thousand line of CSS and when I linked and imported BOOTSTRAP, it started remaking all my styles. In another word, Bootstrap styles and My Own CSS styles are collapsing and making unusable and ugly UI.

**The question is:**
Can I include only style classes that I really need?

Googled :D
I have no XP in this situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the bootstrap documentation I have found that you can download the styles separately, selecting which ones you need

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/#download

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWl7H.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFCoP.png

Comment: Oohhhh, thnx man! I appreciate ya!